# Classification of groups of order 16

Tags: abstract-algebra

I just went through Dummit and Fottee's book of Abstract algebra; I couldn't found unfortunately there any non-abelian group of order 16 in the classification table of the groups of small orders - order 1 to 20.
Can anybody tell me whats wrong with these groups of order 16?

Comment: According to [GroupProps](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Order_of_a_group) there are 14 non-isomorphic groups of order 16. May be they felt that the list was too long to be included in an introductory text?

Answer (score 1):

There are many non-abelian groups of order 16. The simplest example is the group of symmetries of a regular octagon, $D_{16}$.

I believe that they are not listed since a complete classification of the non-abelian groups of order 16 requires some knowledge of semidirect products (which are introduced in the next two sections).

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right. Can you tell me any list of all the groups of order 16?

Comment: Here's a [link](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Groups_of_order_16) to the GroupProps page which lists those groups

Comment: I think even semi-direct products are not enough for every group of order 16.